# Why doesn’t ABPersonViewController show any properties besides the name?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, addressbook

For some reason, `ABPersonViewController` is unwilling to display any properties aside from the name, no matter what properties are set for it to display.

I’m unable to use the `AddressBookUI` controllers to let a user select a contact to display, since my UI has custom requirements, otherwise I’d go that route (as Apple does in their sample project.)

Here’s the code that doesn’t work — am I missing something?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ABContact is of my own creation
    ABContact *contact = [self contactAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    ABPersonViewController *viewController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];

    // This returns a valid ABRecordRef, as indicated by the fact that the 
    // controller does display the name of this contact when it is loaded
    viewController.displayedPerson = contact.record;

    // Copied directly from Apple’s QuickContacts sample project
    NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty], 
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty],
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonBirthdayProperty], nil];

    viewController.displayedProperties = displayedItems;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController: viewController animated: YES];
    [viewController release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The value of these constants is undefined until one of the following functions has been called: ABAddressBookCreate, ABPersonCreate, ABGroupCreate.**

The above is come from [apple document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210). I think those property constants are not valid for above reason.

Comment: What part of "valid ABRecordRef" wasn't clear in my question? I hate to be snarky, but did you even read my sample code?

Comment: Well, good luck to you. I encountered a problem before, because above reason I said, but apparently it is impossible for your case.

Comment: It appears that apple removed this warning from current documentation :-(

Answer (score 3):

ABContact is from Erica Sadun's ObjC wrapper (ABContactsHelper), right?

I'm using it too and found that for some reason, Apple's ABPersonViewController somehow treats supplied ABRecordRef as contact.record differently than if you directly use C functions.
Thus this:

```
ABContact *person = ...;
ABPersonViewController *personVC = ...;
personVC.displayedPerson = person.record;
```

will load almost nothing into the controller. Sometimes first/last name, sometimes not even that. However, if you do this:

```
ABContact *person = ...;
ABPersonViewController *personVC = ...;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
personVC.displayedPerson = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, person.recordID);
```

then it will load everything.

Previous answer says that ABAddressBookCreate is required for the constants to have a value, but this is already done in [ABContactsHelper addressBook] call (first thing I call in my code). This it's really puzzling where it gets lost. But the previous does work, consistently.

Comment: I’ve long worked past this particular bug, but I suspect it has to do with the fact that the `[ABContactsHelper addressBook]` call creates a single instance of `ABAddressBookCreate()`, on another thread. `ABRecordRef`s are not thread-safe, hence the failure. These days, I just use `ABUnknownPersonViewController` in most instances, and it does what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The key is not to release the ABAddressBookRef before displaying the view controller. I create  a static instance in an `+initialize` method and keep it around.

Answer (score -1):

This list of properties only affects displaying "properties choosing dialog" (after person has been choosen).  Person contact's properties like first, middle, last names, company, etc.  are always the same (in both dialogs). If you include kABPersonFirstNameProperty, kABPersonMiddleNameProperty, etc. keys in the list they are ignored, only kABPersonPhoneProperty, kABPersonEmailProperty, etc. have effect.